# App compability a challenge

Tags: android, performance

I just developed an app. It works perfectly well on my phone and It also works 100% on some other android phones. But I just found out that I sent it to a phone and when I clicked a button on it, it shows an error, Although every other button works well too on this other phone. The new phone in which I sent it to that shows an error is a higher version of android. Does it mean that the version of the Android is what is affecting it or what?

Comment: Can you tell what that button does or it will be better if you can post the onClick code of that button

Comment: Please, read [this (how to ask)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and
[this (mcve)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before asking,
as those will help you get more and better answers from the community. Add any relevant detail, such as the onclick listener, the target api, the phone android version, etc

Comment: Oh thanks to you all. I have found out what the error is. I had some bitmap images which were too large in size so they were causing a fatal run time error. This is what the snipped screenshot of my pc looked like.

Answer (score 0):

Yea I just got it working.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4xAY.jpg)The app refused to work on other android versions due to the heap size. This was caused by the fact that I had loaded some bitmap images which seemed too large and it affected the runtime. 
The computer showed me a runtime fatal error in the Android log monitor. Here is a screen shot of it.
Thanks to you all for your support.